Arrangements with Specific Sequences
I am struggling with overcounting for this:

How many arrangements of 4 a’s, 3 b’s, 2 c’s, and 1 d are there so that ‘ba’ and ‘bb’ are both in the sequence?

My approach: 
(1) Count number of sequences with the two blocks ‘ba’ and ‘bb’
(2) Count number of sequences with the block ‘bba’
(3) Subtract sequences with the block ‘bbba’
Answer  = (1) + (2) - (3)
This would yield:
$$\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}+\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}-\frac{7!}{3!\cdot2!}$$
However, I wrote python code to check, and the result should actually be:
$$\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}+\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}-\frac{7!}{3!\cdot2!}\cdot4$$
The term I am subtracting is apparently off by a factor of 4, which is equal to the number of a’s. However, I do not understand the connection or even why we need this factor of 4. Can someone please help me understand this?

Can you explain in a bit more detail how you counted the cases (1), (2), and (3) individually? (e.g., how you reached $\frac{8!}{3! 2!}$)

For (1), I treated each block as a separate entity (denoted X and Y). This is equivalent to arranging XYaaaccd.
For (2), I treated the block as a separate entity (denoted X). This is equivalent to arranging Xaaabccd.
For (3), I treated the block as a separate entity (denoted X). This is equivalent to arranging Xaaaccd.

Are you sure your python code works 100%? Your approach seems correct to me.

Yes. Also, I was working on another problem with the same setup. I just reduced the number of a's, b's, c's, and d's to understand this overcounting issue.

@AltUser Consider the sequence babbaccdaa. It is counted once in (1), once in (2), but not subtracted in (3), so overall it was overcounted once.

I see. So I would also need to subtract the case where there is both 'bba' and 'ba', right?

@AltUser Correct. If you do this, you find that you are still over the correct count. There are probably other overlap cases.

@AltUser Here is another overcounted case: bbabccdaaa.

This is probably not what you are looking for, but I find this approach of block counting to be more complicated than it needs to be. The main issue with it is that once we set the blocks, we can't really control what happens before, in between, and after the blocks, and this matters.
As an example, if we have the size-$4$ block is bbab, if it is followed by an a, then we counted it once in (1), another time in (2), and did not subtract it in (3) - so this is an "overcount" of $1$. On the other hand, if that block is followed by c (say), then it was not counted in (1), it was counted in (2), and not subtracted in (3), so it was correctly counted.
What ends up happening if we proceed in this way is that we get a whole bunch of overlap cases that are hard to keep straight. A skilled counter might be able to see it through, but for me, it is too complex.
I would instead approach the problem by complement (a good approach to attempt in general when the direct count seems unwieldy).
The total number of sequences is $\frac{10!}{4! 3! 2!} = 12600$.
How many sequences don't contain bb? This is easy, if you've seen stars and bars: first permute aaaaccd (which is done in $\frac{7!}{4! 2!} = 105$ ways), then insert the bs into $3$ of the $8$ slots (which is done in $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ ways). This comes out to $(56) (105) = 5880$ sequences that don't contain bb.
Now, how many sequences do contain ba? This can be done similar to your block counting, but it is a lot easier since there is only one thing to keep track of. Via the principle of inclusion and exclusion (PIE), we get $\frac{9!}{3! 2! 2!} - \frac{8!}{2! 2! 2!} + \frac{7!}{3! 2!} = 10500$ (the first term is ba, the second term is $2$ sets of ba, and the third term is $3$ sets of ba). This means $12600 - 10500 = 2100$ sequences don't contain ba.
Finally, how many sequences contain neither bb nor ba? Let's again permute the non-b characters (i.e., aaaaccd) in $105$ ways. Now, when inserting b, we cannot put it before any a, which means instead of $8$ slots, we are left with $4$ slots, of which we pick $3$. There are $4$ ways to do this. So, there are $(4) (105) = 420$ such sequences.
Using PIE, the number of sequences that don't contain at least one of ba, bb is
$$5880 + 2100 - 420 = 7560$$
Therefore, the desired count is
$$12600 - 7560 = \boxed{5040}$$

Thanks for this answer! It is much more clear than my block counting approach, though I understand how to set that up correctly too now. I have one more question. How would the PIE used to count sets with ba translate to a set representation of PIE? I am asking because while the calculation makes sense, I don't see how we would translate it into sets. Ex. set with only one ba, set with two ba and set with three ba. But having the and operator would not make sense for these sets.

@AltUser Glad you found it useful. It's not easy to think about it directly in terms of sets, but you can think of it as "number of sequences with at least one (or two, or three) ba (with systematic overcounting and undercounting)". For my own curiosity, if you were able to figure out all of the overcounting in your approach, can you post it as an answer?

(1) Count number of sequences with the two blocks ‘ba’ and ‘bb’ 
(2) Count number of sequences with the block ‘bba’ 
(3) Count the number of sequences with the blocks ‘bba’ and ‘ba’ 
(4) Count the number of sequences with th block ‘bbba’
Answer  = (1) + (2) - (3) - (4)
This is because all instances of (2) containing a block of ‘bba’ and ‘ba’ are present in (1) and overcounted once. Moreover, all instances of (2) with ‘bbba’ are present in (1) and overcounted once.
This yields:
$$\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}+\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}-\frac{7!}{2!\cdot2!}-\frac{7!}{3!\cdot2!}=5040$$
This method also applies to give the correct answer to the original problem I needed help with:
How many arrangements are there of seven as, eight bs, three cs, and six ds with no occurrence of the consecutive pairs ca or cc?
$$n_1=\frac{23!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot2!\cdot6!}-\frac{22!}{2!\cdot5!\cdot8!\cdot6!}+\frac{21!}{3!\cdot4!\cdot8!\cdot6!}$$
$$n_2=\frac{23!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot6!}-\frac{22!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot6!}$$
$$n_3=\frac{22!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot6!}+\frac{22!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot6!}-\frac{21!}{5!\cdot8!\cdot6!}-\frac{21!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot6!}$$
$$\frac{24!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot3!\cdot6!}-\left(n_1+n_2-n_3\right)=1.588809222\times10^{11}$$

Ah, very nice. Thanks for the writeup!

You should include your solution to the previous problem with that problem so that it can be closed.

This answer is more of a supplement to the correct answer already given by OP. We use PIE the inclusion-exclusion principle to count the number of valid $10$-letter words from the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$ which do contain the  words $\{ba,bb\}$ and which are built from $4a$'s, $3b$'s, $2c$'s and one $d$.

In order to do the job some kind of bookkeeping is helpful. We consider
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\left(ba\ bb\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .|bba\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\right)}\tag{1}\\
&\color{blue}{\quad-\left(ba\ bba\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .|bbba\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\right)}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment:

In (1) we count all $10$-letter words which contain the two substrings $ba$ and $bb$ at least once.

In the first case they are taken as two separate substrings consuming $4$ letters leaving $6$ positions free for the remaining letters. The two substrings can be distributed in $2!\binom{8}{2}$ ways. We can write the number of occurrences as
\begin{align*}
2!\binom{8}{2}\frac{6!}{3!0!2!1!}
\end{align*}
which indicates in the denominator of the fraction that $3a$, $0b$, $2c$ and $1d$ are left for distribution to the remaining $6$ positions.

In the second case $ba$ and $bb$ are taken as an overlapping substring $bba$  leaving $7$ positions free for the remaining letters. This substring can be distributed in $1!\binom{8}{1}$ ways. We can write the number of occurrences as
\begin{align*}
1!\binom{8}{1}\frac{7!}{3!1!2!1!}
\end{align*}
which indicates in the denominator of the fraction that $3a$, $1b$, $2c$ and $1d$ are left for distribution to the remaining $7$ positions.



In (2) we compensate the overcounting from (1) by subtracting all valid occurrences of three words $(ba, ba, bb)$ resp. $(ba, bb, bb)$. These tripel respect that $ba$ and $bb$ need to occur at least once. But since we have only a total of three $b$'s available only some overlappings of these tripels can occur to form valid substrings. In fact there are two possibilities as given in (2). The calculation is done in the same way as in (1).

No more cases are left to consider, since words containing four or more of the substrings $ba$ and $bb$ consume more than $3b$ even in case of overlaps.



We obtain according to (1) and (2):
\begin{align*}
2!&\binom{8}{2}\frac{6!}{3!0!2!1!}+1!\binom{8}{1}\frac{7!}{3!1!2!1!}\\
&-2!\binom{7}{2}\frac{5!}{2!0!2!1!}-1!\binom{7}{1}\frac{6!}{3!0!2!1!}\\
&=3\,360+3\,360-1\,260-420\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=5\,040}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the answer from OP.

